# React Boilerplate Build to External Hosting Server

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-boilerplate

Really have some difficulties building React Boilerplate (https://github.com/react-boilerplate/react-boilerplate) to copy built files to external hosting server.

After `npm run build` command I FTP all generated files into a separate folder at my remote host, say, http://example.com/test/react.

However, all paths inside the app are pointing to / path, so on deeper level (/test/react) the app would not load.

I have not found anything in documentation about this for React Boilerplate. Any help or suggestion?

Comment: I have the same question, and sadly cannot find an answer after plenties of googling